# Pig Latin - distinct count and string comparison in for loop

Tags: apache-pig

I'm trying to to filter users by those ones who have at least two coutries in their profile or they are from the US, I tried this in Pig

```
    B = group A by userid;
    C = foreach B  {
                count = $1.country;
                count2 = distinct count;
                GENERATE (((SIZE(count2) > 1 OR count2.$0 != 'USA') ? group : null)));
        }
```

but it came with this error

```
incompatible types in NotEqual Operator left hand side:bag :tuple(country:chararray)  right hand side:chararray
```

I tried varies other combinations, but no luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
C =
    foreach (group A by userid)
    generate
        group as userid,
        COUNT(A) AS count,
        FLATTEN(A) as country;
D = filter C by count > 1 OR country == 'US';
```

C is a relation with schema {userid:chararray, count:long, country:chararray}, where count is the number of countries that userid is associated with.  D is filtered according to your criteria.

Comment: Thanks, this looks like a good solution, I was trying to solve it in one loop, didn't think this way.